# Debugging Java with JDB and Gradle

Tags: java, gradle, jdb

I have a simple 'HelloWorld' class within a small project that was initiated with Gradle (gradle init --type java-library).  The HelloWorld.java file is located in [project]/src/main/java/HelloWorld.java.  The project gets compiled when I run "gradle build" / "gradle compileJava", etc.

I am trying to debug it using JDB.  I've tried:
%jdb -sourcepath src/main/java HelloWorld
%jdb run HelloWorld
etc..

I am getting "Error: Could not find or load main class Program"

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to add class path as well.

```
-sourcepath provides jdb with location of *.java
-classpath provides jdb with location of *.class
```

You have to call it like this:

```
jdb -sourcepath src/main/java -classpath _location_of_compiled_code_ HelloWorld
```